# Joining sub-lists nested two levels deep in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have an obviously easy task, but I can't do it, and I could not find a solution by searching the site.

I have a list as follows:

```
lis1 = {{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 7}}, {{6, 7, 8}, {4, 2, 2}}}
```

and would like to flatten it to

```
lis = {{1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 7}, {6, 7, 8, 4, 2, 2}}
```

Does anyone have a hint?

Comment: You need to put the right hand side of your first line inside braces (as is it is not a valid expression). Then you can use `Join@@@lis1` or `Map[Flatten, lis1, 1]` or `Flatten/@lis1` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presuming that your data really is given by

```
data = {{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 7}}, {{6, 7, 8}, {4, 2, 2}}};
```

then I would use `Join` and `Apply` (at level 1),

```
Join @@@ data
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 7}, {6, 7, 8, 4, 2, 2}}
> ```